# make distcheck permission denied

Tags: autotools

In my src directory I have the interface file `neoleo.i` which is used by swig to create `neoleo_wrap.c` via the rule:

```
neoleo_wrap.c : $(srcdir)/neoleo.i neoleo_swig.c neoleo_swig.h
        swig -tcl8 $(srcdir)/neoleo.i
```

When I type `make dist ; make distcheck` it outputs:

```
swig -tcl8 ../../../src/neoleo.i
Unable to open file ../../../src/neoleo_wrap.c: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1313: neoleo_wrap.c] Error 1
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Some relevant parts of my `Makefile.am`:

```
EXTRA_DIST = $(srcdir)/neoleo.i
BUILT_SOURCES = getdate.c parse.c parse.h posixtm.c posixtm.h neoleo_wrap.c
nodist_libneoleo_la_SOURCES = neoleo_wrap.c
neoleo_wrap.c : $(srcdir)/neoleo.i neoleo_swig.c neoleo_swig.h
        swig -tcl8 $(srcdir)/neoleo.i
```

Complete `Makefile.am` available here:

[Makefile.am](https://github.com/blippy/neoleo/blob/master/src/Makefile.am)

Comment: This is an automake question, not a makefile question.  Please adjust your tags.

Comment: Follow-up question: is it a convention to include or exclude the generated wrapper code with the tarball?

Comment: Most of the time you'd include the generated wrapper in the tarball, so people can build the result without having to have `swig` installed.  But if they need it installed anyway for some reason, then it doesn't really matter which way you go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

automake `distcheck` verifies that your build system behaves correctly according to its standards and part of that is that the source directory is not modified in any way.  distcheck uses permissions to ensure this.  In your case, `swig` is trying to write its output file to the source directory which is not right (according to automake): that directory must not be modified.

Even if you didn't care about this, your makefile is wrong because it says that your rule will build `neoleo_wrap.c`, but your `swig` command line will actually create `../../src/neoleo_wrap.c`; make will not forgive this betrayal.

So, you need to change your `swig` command to something like:

```
neoleo_wrap.c : $(srcdir)/neoleo.i neoleo_swig.c neoleo_swig.h
        swig -tcl8 -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! This fixes the issue.I seem to have spent more time cajoling autotools into doing what I want than actual C programming. I made the src/Makefile.am available as a gist for reference purposes: https://gist.github.com/blippy/6120a53c10ae438c37399c29e795ef53

Comment: The thing about using autotools is it makes you consider the end-user's needs up-front before someone send you a bug report about it: end-users want to build out of tree, they want to use cross compilers, they want various other things.  autoconf and automake ensure that all those things are available in your package... but of course to get them you have to make sure it's behaving correctly.